# Making optional Windows update permanent

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, ms-security-essentials

Is there a way I can selectively make some optional Windows updates permanent? In particular I'm looking to make the definition updates for Microsoft Security Essentials permanent.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article could help : [Microsoft Security Essentials Automatic Virus Signature Updates](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/microsoft-security-essentials-automatic-virus-signature-update/).

The article describes how one can use the build-in Windows Task Scheduler
to check for Microsoft Security Essentials Signature Updates on daily, weekly, or monthly basis, without requiring the scheduling of a scan.

[image]

Comment: Happy this worked. FYI it is not enough to accept - the bounty has to be manually awarded.

Comment: Here is a link to a way to change the frequency of MSE updates. The default is every 24 hours.

http://lifehacker.com/5733597/change-microsoft-security-essentials-update-frequency

Answer (score 1):

If you have it check for updates prior to scanning, and scan at least once a day, that's a sort of automation. Otherwise I think you would have to run a script of some sort to scan the names of available optional updates and install anything with Security Essentials in the name. Microsoft doesn't make a method available to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not set the MSE updtaes as required or permanent. Setting the MSE updates as required or important could make it seem that MSE is a required installation for Windows. This would then lead to some legal issues. See this article from Computer World

http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9195079/Rival_calls_foul_over_Microsoft_s_delivering_Security_Essentials_via_Windows_Update

If you set up a scheduled scan,  MSE will download the updates before it starts the scan.

To set a scheduled scan open up MSE and click on the settings tab. Check the box "Run a scheduled scan" and set the day, time, and type of scan. Then make sure the box for "Check for the latest virus & spyware definitions before running a scheduled scan" is checked.